# How to run an R file on schedule basis? Preferably on the cloud

Tags: r, r-markdown, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, power-automate

How can I run an R script on an automatic schedule either locally, or better on the cloud? I have tried to create a batch file unsuccessfully. If I could schedule the file to run through MS Power Automate that would be perfect. Any ideas?

Comment: Cron. Task scheduler. Connect (and scheduled rmarkdown documents). Or put your "R script" in a plumber api (in your cloud) and hit the http endpoint via some (possibly local) cron or task-scheduler job.

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans. Do you have an opportunity to show me how? I could not get Task Scheduler to work. My scripts name is "run.R" and it contains the following code:                                                                  


setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)) #Sets WD to source file location.

library(rmarkdown)

render("AVA-Logistics-Report.Rmd")
render("Shipments Report Germany.Rmd")
render("Shipments Report Norway.Rmd")
render("Shipments Report UK.Rmd")

Comment: Were your problems based on getting Task Scheduler to run something periodically? Was it getting TS to run `Rscript.exe`? Or is it that your script is running and not giving you the expected results?